# MacPorts to automatically install dependencies

Tags: macos, command-line, macports, open-source

I installed 6 packages in one command, and it prompted me 6 times.  I’m using Mac ports on macOS Catalina 10.15

```
The following dependencies will be installed: 
Continue? [Y/n]:
```

Is there any command-line option to suppress the following prompt?

Comment: Odd it normally does that only once

Comment: I’ve added a current macOS version. Feel free to edit this if I guessed wrong.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I recommend asking on the MacPorts Users mailing list. They've been extremely helpful to me in the past. https://lists.macports.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacPort's port is reasonable documented so on of the normal ways to find help
e.g.

1. `man port`
2. `port help`

will give the way

> -N
> Non-interactive mode, interactive questions are not asked

So run

```
sudo port -N install <portname>
```